# How to use `gcloud config` to build an image based on `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk`

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I am trying to build an image based on `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine`, with some configuration I already know on build time. After some testing with `gcloud config set` on my local system, I transposed these commands into my Dockerfile. Although the sequence of commands yields the expected *final* gcloud configuration on my computer, the behaviour I found on the docker image was different and no change was persisted after the `RUN` commands.

I didn't expect this behaviour. What should explain this?

I used the following Dockerfile to assess the issue during troubleshoot:

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine AS runner
  RUN ["gcloud", "config", "list"]
  RUN ["gcloud", "config", "set", "compute/region", "europe-west1"]
  RUN ["gcloud", "config", "list"]
  ENTRYPOINT [ "bash" ]
```

One can see that step 2/5 and step 4/5 yield the same output, even though the step 3/4 should change the *current* gcloud configuration for `compute/region`.

```sh
$ docker build --no-cache .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine AS runner
 ---> e3ce7ea1a190
Step 2/5 : RUN ["gcloud", "config", "list"]
 ---> Running in b8fb806b04aa
[component_manager]
disable_update_check = true
[core]
disable_usage_reporting = true
[metrics]
environment = github_docker_image

Your active configuration is: [default]
Removing intermediate container b8fb806b04aa
 ---> bc8321e71e60
Step 3/5 : RUN ["gcloud", "config", "set", "compute/region", "europe-west1"]
 ---> Running in cfbcb80b1a31
Updated property [compute/region].
Removing intermediate container cfbcb80b1a31
 ---> db76ee7c5e60
Step 4/5 : RUN ["gcloud", "config", "list"]
 ---> Running in d90c64fcf0b0
[component_manager]
disable_update_check = true
[core]
disable_usage_reporting = true
[metrics]
environment = github_docker_image

Your active configuration is: [default]
Removing intermediate container d90c64fcf0b0
 ---> a593aa61055e
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT [ "bash" ]
 ---> Running in acb4d360754c
Removing intermediate container acb4d360754c
 ---> edab55257026
Successfully built edab55257026
```

cloud-builders
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud` config is persisted in `/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default`

BUT `/root/.config` and `/root/.kube` are `VOLUME`s and can't be changed:

```
VOLUME ["/root/.config", "/root/.kube"]
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker/blob/8764ec3c23860b35e9a7883c74ca2b4a6b45d866/Dockerfile#L42

"If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded."

see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

Comment: You're welcome! You could fork Google's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) and use a non-`VOLUME` step.

Comment: Sure, but then I'd have to manage `gcloud auth`. I'll handle it on the entrypoint :)